# Create a forward proxy on a Linux server

Tags: proxy

Situation: I have 2 Linux boxes running a LAMP stack. I want to access HTTP from box1 via box2 (using wget and curl). I want people using box2 to see no change at all.

What's the best solution? I need something easy to setup if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to be more specific; why would users notice *anything* from box2? Is the intention to serve content from box1 without any intermediate processing? Or is box2 making requests of box1 while in the process of generating the content that users have requested? Where is the *proxy* in the question?

If you want requests made of box2 to be transparently handled by box1 in the background, ignore wget / curl and and configure [Apache mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html).

If you're trying to build a *cache* of responses from box1 to be served via box2, then perhaps running [Squid in reverse proxy mode](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/ReverseProxy) makes more sense. It's already made for caching. :) (Building caching into your application on box1 might be the better long-term answer; it is pretty easy in Ruby-on-Rails applications to add fragment caching and page caching to the application, and memcached can be used to add model-caching behavior, different from caching fragments or whole pages. This approach lets you easily *expire* pages when the data on those pages is *invalidated*, something that would be difficult to do with squid or hand-rolling curl/wget page loading tricks.)

If you just want to keep box1 hidden on the happy side of a firewall, you could use firewall *port forwarding* to forward the one specific port to the inside. (Even on box2; nothing says that the machine doing the forwarding actually needs two NICs.)